# Create azure VM on my local machine

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-role

Is it possible to create one or several azure VMs on my local machine? I want to create a web app and load test it locally, without the need of putting it in the cloud. I'm thinking at the following scenario: I have a local VM running a IIS server with my web app; I use a tool to generate a lot of load; I need to deploy the second VM containing the same things as the first VM. The downtime of the web app should be equal to 0(hopefully).

**Clarification(update):**
I want to achieve the following: create a web app and a monitoring app(CPU,Memory) and deploy them on one VM. On a load test, if the VM cannot handle it(e.g. CPU goes above 80%), I want to programmatically deploy a new VM(with the same configuration, having both the web app and the monitoring app), such that no downtime occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure has several ways for you to host sites.

- Virtual Machines is just that, normal VMs. You can create them locally and upload them, but everything is up to you, including how to handle upgrades. If that is what you need to do then I don't know how you would handle upgrades with no down time; though, you can add multiple VMs to a load balancer and then upgrade them one at a time.
- It sounds like what you really want to explore is Cloud Services. You can run one or more VMs locally in the emulator, upgrade with no down time once in the cloud, implement auto scaling (you will have to use a tool or write some code).
- Alternatively you may want to look at Azure Web sites,  but that is a completely different concept and you can't really test load and load balancing locally the same way.

Based on your statement that you essentially want to auto-scale your application you want to look at Cloud Services with Auto Scaling. However, you can't fully test this in the cloud emulator - but you can test your logic.

### Background

Azure Cloud Services is designed for this kind of thing; You don't really work with VMs in the way you may be used to, instead you create a package that Azure then deploys to as many servers as you like. Once up and running, you can manually go into the management console and increase or decrease the number of active servers simply by moving a slider. Of course, you want to do this automatically, so you have a few options.

There is a management API you can use to change the number of servers. So, it would be quite simple to write a bit of code that you spin up in another thread from WebRole.Start and that simply sits and monitors the CPU on the machine and then calls the management API to spin up a new server instance if your CPU goes over a certain treshold. Okay, locally you can only test that the call to the management API is made, you won't actually see the new server coming up. But, if you grab your free trial of Azure and just try it you will see that you really don't need to test that part - it just works.

However, in practice there is an awful lot more to auto scaling. Here are some of the things you need to consider;

- Even relatively idle web servers will often spike briefly to 100% so just having a simple treshold is unlikely to be good enough; You need to decide on how long the server needs to be over a certain treshold before you spin up another server instance.
- What happens when you have more than one server? And, on Azure, you should always have at least two servers to ensure you have resilience. Note that the idea with Cloud Services really is to have many small servers rather than a few big servers. You pay per core, not per number of servers.

  - Imagine you currently have three servers and one is really busy for some reason and the other two are idle. Do you want to spin up a fourth server?
  - Imagine you currently have two servers and they are both quite busy. Do you really want them *both* to start a new server so you end up with four servers running?

There are several ways to handle these challenges. For starters, rather than having monitor programs running locally on each server, you are better of moving that monitoring outside; Azure comes with the ability to dump performance metrics to table storage at whatever interval you choose. You can then run an external program that retrieves the performance data over time from all your current servers and then reason about the overall workload before deciding to spin up or shut down additional servers. Now, you can of course host that external monitor program in a separate thread on each of your webroles to give your monitoring resilience - but the key point is that the monitoring program doesn't monitor the server it runs on, it monitors all the servers. You will, of course, still have to deal with stopping multiple monitoring program instances from all starting and stopping servers. One way to do is to place stop/start commands onto an Azure "message queue" (there are a few different types) and use the built-in "de-duper" which will automatically delete identical commands  that are put on the queue within a certain time window (I am over simplyfing but you get the idea).

### The actual answer

Really, though, you want to look at the [Auto Scaling Application Block](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/autoscaling/) which will do most of this for you. I guess that is the real answer to your question, but I wanted to provide a bit of context first.
Again, I recognise you asked for how to test this locally - but I believe that that question doesn't really make sense in the context of Azure and I hope the above information helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I want to achieve the following: create a web app and a monitoring app(CPU,Memory) and deploy them on one VM. On a load test, if the VM cannot handle it(e.g. CPU goes above 80%), I want to programmatically deploy a new VM(with the same configuration, having both the web app and the monitoring app), such that no downtime occurs. From your answer I understand that this is possible(locally) with the emulator. I hope the question is clear know. :)

Comment: Hi Alex, I have re-written my answer. Please update your question to reflect the clarification you put in the comment to help future users searching for something similar. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't do that and it wouldn't make sense anyway. If you want load testing, you need to run that in an environment as similar to production as possible and that means you have to run your application is Azure cloud. How else do you know that the load will actually be processed fine on real cloud?

Comment: Well yeah, I see your point, and you are somewhat correct. But I want to create a proof-of-concept how every web app(supposing its the only app deployed on a server) should have a monitoring app attached to it in order to scale up/down(you can think that the whole concept is something similar to a ecosystem). Going further with the idea think at "Green Systems", i.e. system that are aware of the context(in this case the server/vm) which fire up servers when needed and close servers when they are not needed anymore(saving energy, resources, etc.).

Comment: @Alex Ivan: Well, if you need just a proof of concept - I guess the system making "right decisions" and say queuing messages for scaling up and down would be enough and you don't need multiple VMs for that. In my experience Azure has a rather steep learning curve, so if you were presenting your proof of concept to me I wouldn't be satisfied before I saw it working in Azure anyway.